# Disable install feature based on existing services

Tags: windows-services, wix, wix3.7

I'm writing an installer that will install a Windows Service. I've already configured the service to be dependent upon a 3rd party service, and that works fine. I want to start the service as part of the installation, but if the 3rd party service does not exist, it will error.

Ideally I'd like to not even allow the feature to be available for install if the 3rd party service isn't installed. It looks like I should be able to use the `<Condition>` tag in the `<Feature>` and set the level to an arbitrarily high number, but I have no idea what is available to me for that condition. I've searched around online and haven't found a good resource on what is and is not available for me to test in the condition inner text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can detect the service from a well-known registry key, use the [WiX RegistrySearch element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) to set a property and use that property in your condition's expression. For example, from the WiX setup:

```
<Condition Level="1">VS2005DEVENV OR VS2005_ROOT_FOLDER OR REMOVE</Condition>
```

Comment: I decided to go a different route, but this answer does solve the question that I posted -- Thanks!